# how can concatenate the set variable in a for loop to be use as name in an input to get the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can concatenate the set variable in a for loop to be use as name in an input to get the value?

```
<script>
var k=0;
var counter = 50;

    for(k=0; k<=counter; k++){
        var choices = $('input[name=choices'+ k]).val();
        var choices = choices.replace(/\ /g, '%');
        var choices_ = choices_ +";"+ choices;
    }
   alert(choices);
</script>
```

there are multiple input field namely choices1,choices2 and so on.
how can i get the value of those fields using for loop?
how can i concatenate the name choices and the variable k?
can you help me solve this problem??

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with
choices = choices +";"+ choices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just iterate using a specialized attribute selector and `.each()`:

```
var choices = $('input[name^="choices"]'),  // name starts with "choices"
    choices_val = []                        // an array!
    ;

choices.each(function () {
    choices_val.push($(this).val().replace(/\ /g, '%'));
});

alert(choices_val.join(';'));
```

It saves you the overhead (and headache) of having to pick out and mangle a specific attribute value (`choices1`, `choices2`, etc) **and** having to select it out via selector ('cause I'd think that selecting via `$(this)` is faster than `$('input[name="choices1"]')`).

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `choices` three times, which is invalid and will lead to many errors.

Comment: the error is in line var choices = $('input[name=choices'+ k]).val();

Comment: You're missing some quotes there. `$('input[name="choices' + k + '"]').val()`

Answer (score 2):

You use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery, it's identical as for loop.

Say for example you have this HTML:

```
​<input type ="text" name="field1" value="Alpha" />
<input type ="text" name="field2" value="Bravo" />
<input type ="text" name="field3" value="Charlie" />​
```

And here is the js file:

```
var k = 1;
$('input').each(function(e) {
    alert('choices' + k + '=' + $(this).val());
    k++;
});​
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/v5qG8/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=choices'+ k +']').val();
```

you just forget to put another + sign and single quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed 2 quotes and a +.

$('input[name=choices' + k + ']').val();

Answer (score 0):

add quotes

```
    var choices = $('input[name=choices'+ k + ']').val();
```

use css selector

```
$(".className").each(function(){
       $(this).myFunction();
})

jQuery.fn.myFunction = function()

        var choices = $(this).val();
        var choices = choices.replace(/\ /g, '%');
        var choices_ = choices_ +";"+ choices;
}
```